# Creating subdomains using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, subdomain

I have a question in regards to creating subdomains using C#. So the idea behind this is that a user can create a subdomain on our web application like following:

```
username.example.com
```

Or

```
  username2.example.com
```

I'm familiar with static/dynamic routes. I'm guessing this can be done with one of those or with virtual directory?

How can this be performed in C# and .NET?

Comment: Note you'll also have to handle this on the DNS side, or direct any non-matching A record requests to your server.

Comment: @john yes I supposed so... I'd just need some good answer from someone to clarify the things a bit for everyone who wants to know more on this topic...

Comment: I don't know enough about the IIS side of this to give an answer, but just wanted to make sure you don't forget :)

Comment: @john thx for that =) I wonder if there's someone who'll reply soon

Comment: Anyone guys ? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let’s say that you have a dedicate IP to your site to avoid the binding on the IIS

Second step, let say that you use the BIND for dns, so you open the correct txt file and adds or remove there the correct subdomain with an update to the time stamp, and a restart the BIND service with a command call from asp.net… (you need to know some basic for DNS, and give access to the pool to been able to read/write there)

Then you can read on the very first call on global.asax `Application_BeginRequest` the

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Path
```

That contains the subdomain as well, and translate it using the

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath
```

To something like

```
username.example.com  -> example.com/users.aspx?userid=123456
```

This is the general idea all together (this is on **global.asax**)...

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sThePathToReWrite = sFindTheRealPath();

    if (sThePathToReWrite != null){
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(sThePathToReWrite, false);
    }       
}

string sFindTheRealPath()
{
    string strCurrentPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;   

    // analyze the strCurrentPath 
    // find for example the userid from the url
    // and return the translate one - if not find anything return null
    return "example.com/users.aspx?userid=" + userid        
}
```

Comment: Okay hold on I'm gonna check it out =)

Comment: @User987 I have implement that scenario but I do not have some specific source code to show you because it’s a complex one that’s include database read and setup. But this is the general idea, the basic steps.

Comment: could you post the source code for the url rewrite part at least ? =) I'll find a way for db read/write setup

Comment: @User987 all the difficult code is to analyze the `Request.Path` and extract the "username"... then you just call this `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("example.com/users.aspx?userid=12345", false);`

Comment: @User987 I have copy/paste the base code that I have